# pass an empty argument into an scheduled task xml file

Tags: xml, events, scheduled-tasks, event-log, windows-server

I am trying to run a batch file when some specific events occurs and I want to pass some null arguments to one of my tasks. The problem is that I don't know how. 
I have tried a lot of combinations but without success.
My xml files looks something like:

```
    ........

      <ValueQueries>
            <Valuename="TargetUserName">Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TargetUserName']</Value>
            <Value name="EventID">Event/System/EventID</Value>
      </ValueQueries>

    ......

   <Exec>
      <Command>C:\passwd.bat</Command>
      <Arguments>$(TargetUserName) $(SubjectUserName) $(EventID) </Arguments>
    </Exec>
```

Now, I would like to pass an empty argument [between $(TargetUserName) and $(EventID)] for one of my events but I didn't manage to do this yet.

Any suggestions ?